# Parsing XML format with child nodes using plsql

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I am new to xml format and sql and I have an issue. I have a  SQL query that returns the xml like the one below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1250"?>
<AROUND>
  <AB>
    <Connected>1</Connected>
    <EF>1010</EF>
    <GH>10162</GH>
    <IJ>HG-131120CXD</IJ>
    <KL>New</KL>
    <MN>284822</MN>
  </AB>
  <AB>
    <Connected>0</Connected>
    <EF>2123</EF>
    <GH>54321</GH>
    <IJ>HG-131120BRE</IJ>
    <KL>Old</KL>
    <MN>284822</MN>
  </AB>
  <AB>
    <Connected>1</Connected>
    <EF>4321</EF>
    <GH>12345</GH>
    <IJ>HG-131120DYX</IJ>
    <KL>New</KL>
    <MN>284822</MN>
  </AB>
</AROUND>
```

and I have to extract **some** of the values from it (for example: **Connected, GH, IJ, KL**) using a query so that every **AB** part of it, no matter how much of them are there (in this example there are 3, but there could be 1-10 or even more), has it's own row. For example (**Connected, GH, IJ, KL**), first row would be: 1 10162 HG-131120CXD New. And so on, and so on...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really mean PL/SQL; or just Oracle-flavour SQL? PL/SQL is a [a procedural extension](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/overview.html).

Comment: SQL , my bad, I am a noob, sry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [XMLTable()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html#GUID-F4508470-D420-4B5A-B5DF-59A424887F10) to extract the data you want from your XML document; something like:

```
select x.connected, x.gh, x.ij, x.kl
from your_query q
cross apply xmltable (
  '/AROUND/AB'
  passing q.xml_doc
  columns
    connected number path 'Connected',
    gh number path 'GH',
    ij varchar2(20) path 'IJ',
    kl varchar2(10) path 'KL'
) x
```

where `your_query` is whatever query currently generates your XML document. If it generates a string value then you can wrap that in `XMLType()` to convert it.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6de9c4bcfe4b8fc2ce9444556b08a500) showing both, using a CTE to represent your existing query to produce an XML document or string value, to get:

```
CONNECTED |    GH | IJ           | KL 
--------: | ----: | :----------- | :--
        1 | 10162 | HG-131120CXD | New
        0 | 54321 | HG-131120BRE | Old
        1 | 12345 | HG-131120DYX | New
```

You can use that SQL statement within a PL/SQL block like any other SQL; if the XML document is in a variable you can do something like:

```
for r in (
  select x.connected, x.gh, x.ij, x.kl
  from xmltable (
    '/AROUND/AB'
    passing l_xml_doc -- local XMLType variable
    columns
      connected number path 'Connected',
      gh number path 'GH',
      ij varchar2(20) path 'IJ',
      kl varchar2(10) path 'KL'
  ) x
) loop
  -- do something with r.connected, r.gh etc.
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two [XPath expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-xml.html) with a [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html). With the first you split the `AB` nodes and with the second you concatenate the relevant elements into a string.

```sql
with tmp as (
select unnest (xpath ('//AB',
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1250"?>
<AROUND>
  <AB>
    <Connected>1</Connected>
    <EF>1010</EF>
    <GH>10162</GH>
    <IJ>HG-131120CXD</IJ>
    <KL>New</KL>
    <MN>284822</MN>
  </AB>
  <AB>
    <Connected>0</Connected>
    <EF>2123</EF>
    <GH>54321</GH>
    <IJ>HG-131120BRE</IJ>
    <KL>Old</KL>
    <MN>284822</MN>
  </AB>
  <AB>
    <Connected>1</Connected>
    <EF>4321</EF>
    <GH>12345</GH>
    <IJ>HG-131120DYX</IJ>
    <KL>New</KL>
    <MN>284822</MN>
  </AB>
</AROUND>')) ab
)
select unnest (xpath ('concat(//Connected/text()," ",//GH/text()," ",//IJ/text()," ",//KL/text())', tmp.ab)) ab
from tmp;
```

This returns:

```
            ab            
--------------------------
 1 10162 HG-131120CXD New
 0 54321 HG-131120BRE Old
 1 12345 HG-131120DYX New
```

Comment: The question is tagged for Oracle, not PostgreSQL, so this syntax won't work for the OP.

Comment: @AlexPoole Indeed I missed it.